# How can I make a batch file run onstartup without me having to add it?

Tags: windows, boot, batch

There was a bit of confusion before when I asked this, but I need this batch file to add itself to startup without the user knowing. I know it sounds kinda sketchy, but it for new software I am making

Comment: what do you mean by "itself". The user must at least run some file/script/executable.

Comment: I mean like what command can a batch file do to add itself to startup?

Lets say you run the file, what command can it do to start on startup?

Comment: Easiest way is to copy it to the startup folder or to create a shortcut to your file: %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

Comment: @TJJ Thanks I will try this out.

Comment: Your title needs help. It's clear you want a progmatic way to configure the OS to run a batch file in startup. It's confusing to ask how to do that *without me having to* X. You obviously have to do *something* to accomplish this.

Comment: @TJJ You need to post an answer. Please avoid putting answers in comments. As explained in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment) "Comments are not recommended for any of the following...Answering a question or providing an alternate solution to an existing answer; instead, post an actual answer (or edit to expand an existing one)."

Comment: Let me makes this clear: How could you make a batch file add itself to startup when you run it? So if I run file.bat, what command can I add to make it add itself to startup?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to copy it to the startup folder or to create a shortcut to your file:

%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

This will run the script every time the specific user logs in.

You could implement a check in your batch to see if the copy/shortcut already exists in the startup folder, and if it is not there, the file will copy itself/create the shortcut of itself in the startup folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here some suggest for command that can be used to add on the registry subkeys values entries for execute in bat and go make these call it self to fit/following your needs/scenery:

---

```bat
rem :: For all boot in local machine (apply to all users) use this key::
rem :: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

rem ::  This is an command for run in your bat and for execute it self in all next boot and for all users:
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v _Some_Uniq_Value_ /d "%~f0" /f >nul

rem :: For check if reg add command works, you can use this command :: 
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" | find "_Some_Uniq_Value_"

rem :: ——————————————————————-

rem :: For only in next boot in local machine (apply to machine) use this key ::
rem :: HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

rem :: This is an command for run in your bat for execute one time it self in next boot ::
reg add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v _Some_Uniq_Value_ /d "%~f0" /f >nul

rem :: For check if reg add command works, you can use this command :: 
reg query "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" | find "_Some_Uniq_Value_"

rem :: ——————————————————————-

rem :: For all boot in local machine (apply only to current user) use this key::
rem :: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

rem ::  This is an command for run in your bat for execute it self in all next boot and for the current user:
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v _Some_Uniq_Value_ /d "%~f0" /f >nul

rem :: For check if reg add command works, you can use this command:: 
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" | find "_Some_Uniq_Value_"

rem :: ——————————————————————

rem :: For only in next boot in local machine (apply only to current user) ::
rem :: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce

rem :: This is an command for run in your bat for execute one time it self in next boot and for the current user ::
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v _Some_Uniq_Value_ /d "%~f0" /f >nul

rem :: For check if reg add command works, you can use :: 
reg query "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" | find "_Some_Uniq_Value_"

rem :: ——————————————————————-
```

---

Obs.: you bat will run this command with not replications entries, only re-write the same values...

The **`%~fi`** refere to full path to bat file, so, run your bat in the same where you will call then...

---

So sorry my limited English!